# property 'filter' does not exist on type 'string' in interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface

I have interfaces:

```
export interface ISomeInterface {
   id: string;
   action: string;
   newValue: IValue[] | string;
   oldValue: IValue[] | string;
}

interface IValue {
   id: string
   name: string 
}
```

and I try to call methods for array filter:

```
const entry: ISomeInterface;
let result = entry.newValue.filter(({ id }) => !entry.oldValue.find((el) => el.id === id))
```

And get error: `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'string | IValue[]'`.

Comment: You should have a single type. But for a quick fix, maybe try `(entry.newValue as IValue[]).filter...`

Comment: filter does not exist on string types. Since newValue can be both an array or string, TS throws this error.

Comment: Filter doesn't exist on strings. Can newValue be an array of both IValue and string?

Comment: @Emilien it works, thank u. But you are right, I should to rewrite following using single type!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because `filter` is a method that's available only for arrays and you've set your `newValue` property to be an array of strings OR a string. Strings do not have a `filter` method.

As the above comment correctly points in the right direction, use parentheses to separate the object from the `filter` function AND set the type as follows:

```
let result = (entry.newValue as string[]).filter(({ id }) => !entry.oldValue.find((el) => el.id === id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses to separate the object from the *filter* function

`let result = (entry.newValue).filter(({ id }) => !entry.oldValue.find((el) => el.id === id))`

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't help, if only make like that (entry.newValue as IValue)

Answer (score 0):

trying to judge the type of newValue at first, and if it is an array, you can then use filter